# Why is this knockout foreach binding with jQuery resize animation unreliable?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-animate

Add 16 cards to your "hand" by clicking at random on the aces.  Then, delete cards at random, by clicking on the card in your hand that you want to delete from your hand. Delete them all. Delete at random. Keep track of the number of clicks you're making. Every few turns, it takes *fewer than 16* clicks to remove all the cards from your hand -- every now and then, 2 cards are removed with one click.

http://jsfiddle.net/7z7kP/4/

Is there a bug in my code that I'm overlooking?

```
self.afterAdd = function(element) {         
    var el = $(element);            
    el.addClass( el.text() );
    el.click( function(event) {
        el.animate({width: 0, height: 0}, 222, function() {
            self.hand.splice(el.index(),1);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can safely reproduce when 2 cards disappear: Double click on any ace and you will get two cards on your hand (as expected). But they seem to share the same click handler, thus both are animated, but only one is removed from your hand (the observableArray).

After the animation was removed, this behaviour didn't reoccur, so I assume there's something nasty going on.

```
self.afterAdd = function(element){         
    var el = $(element);            
    el.addClass( el.text() );
    el.click( function(event) {
        var idx = el.index();
        self.hand.splice(idx,1);
    });
};
```

I wanted to give you a nice [CSS3 based solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kzVQc/) for the hide animation (via a simple `el.addClass("hide");`), but that didn't work out as expected. Again both cards disappeared, but then one reappeared. -.-

```
.hide {
  -webkit-animation: hidecard 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hidecard {
    0% { height: 0; width: 0; opacity: 1; }
    100% { height: 0; width: 0; opacity: 0; display:none; }
}
```

Comment: I can get the anomalous behavior even by slowly single-clicking on one of the four aces. It doesn't take a double-click. But I haven't been able to reproduce the problem when  the animation is removed.  Also, I do indeed need to remove the item, not merely hide it. That is a requirement.

Comment: @Tim The elements are removed automatically as soon as you call `splice()`.

Comment: Correct. When the element is removed from the observableArray, knockout removes it from the DOM. Problem is, when using animation, clicking on the element to remove it will remove TWO elements.